# Is it possible to correctly type a generator function with extra behavior in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

Generator functions have `prototype` properties that you can add behavior to.  The generators returned from these functions have this behavior.  But TypeScript appears to be blind to this, and I don't see how to make it aware.

For example, suppose I have a simple range generator, and I want to add a `map` behavior:

```js
/** Returns a generator that yields ints from 0 to `hi`, stepped by `step`. */
function* range(hi: number, step: number = 1) {
  for (let i = 0; i < hi; i += step) {
    yield i;
  }
}
range.prototype.map = function*<T>(fn: (arg0: number) => T) {
  for (const i of this) {
    yield fn(i);
  }
};
```

Unfortunately, this won't work.  Something like `range(9).map(i => 9 - i)` yields the error `Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Generator<number, void, unknown>'.`

(To be clear, the code works.  Only the TS typing doesn't work.)

I'm fantasizing about some syntax to let me specify the behavior, if TS can't figure it out itself.  Something like

```js
interface of range {
  map<R>(fn: (i: number) => R): Generator<R>;
}
```

Is there some magic way to do this I haven't discovered?  Or is it on anyone's radar to add to the language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While TypeScript supports [expando properties on functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#properties-declarations-on-functions), it does not seem to have any analogous support for expanding the `prototype` generator functions.  For `class`es, you can [merge declarations into the instance interface](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#merging-interfaces) and modify the `prototype` later.  But there does not seem to be an appropriate named interface to merge into for generator functions.  There is an open issue at [microsoft/TypeScript#36086](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/36086) that asks for some way to allow what you're trying to do, but there has been no activity there.  If you want to see this happen you could go to that issue, give it a , and describe your use case and why it is compelling... but given that you would be the first person to do so, I can't imagine that implementing that will be prioritized for the foreseeable future.

So if you want this behavior from TypeScript, it's not going to happen automatically.  Instead you'll have to do it yourself.  Here's one possible approach:

```
function augmentGenerator<T, M, A extends any[]>(gf: (...a: A) => Generator<T>,
    m: M & ThisType<Generator<T> & M>
) {
    Object.assign(gf.prototype, m);
    return gf as (...a: A) => (Generator<T> & M);
}
```

The idea is that instead of declaring your generator function and then subsequently adding to the prototype, you call `augmentGenerator` with a generator function (of type `(...a: A) => Generator<T>` and a set of intended prototype modifications (of type `M`), and the compiler returns a generator function whose type is narrowed the way you expect (of type `(...a: A) => (Generator<T> & M)`).

I'm using [the `ThisType<T>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#thistypetype) to provide context when you call `augmentGenerator`, so that the compiler realizes that `this` inside your `m` refers to an appropriate generator.

Let's try it out:

```
const range = augmentGenerator(function* (hi: number, step: number = 1) {
    for (let i = 0; i < hi; i += step) {
        yield i;
    }
}, {
    map: function*<T>(fn: (arg0: number) => T) {
        for (const i of this) {
            yield fn(i);
        }
    }
});
```

That compiles fine; if we now inspect the type of `range()`, we see:

```
/* const range: (hi: number, step?: number | undefined) => 
   Generator<number> & {
     map: <T>(fn: (arg0: number) => T) => Generator<T>;
   } */
```

That's what you wanted.  And therefore, the following works both at runtime, and at compile time:

```
for (const i of range(9).map(i => 9 - i)) {
    console.log(i.toFixed(2)); // 9.00, 8.00, etc
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.2.3#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEApeIA2AvJBvAUPksUgGYCuw8ALgJYD2wSI5A5pMNQOITAQBOIavX4AeACoAaJAFlpAQSQQAHtV4ATKM2ABPANoBdAHwAKVqQBcSEwDo7IK-ICUSALxGkPPoOFjxRySISYLArGSQAMiRxAAtaKHEdGAhRLwEhEQkPKJkjIOIXAmDggHkAIwArCBobECgoWlZgM1IbGH56YWokiGkwJwBufOL+CGpyfiZzZi1be0cXd2s0n0z-SNlB4YBfQmD4RihqJEFgVmRXZjYObl503xMKKjpGACprOKtgcjAygWkjhAYF8fn9+G4kABGQrDYKkETWDBjJC0CEABgGKKQoiQcUxqIA1JdATAYcVyUgdLQIBh1CihhSkLtgttpEUKWAQMCyJQaAxgK8so9gFYTCB+Kw0SDfgJFh5xGTGSR4eCTAdgEcsfRSEhqHEoIqlcUqTS6aRmrQtkbiMyKbabVthgB6d7qzWnc6iz5Ib4y-gAtQwAD80rBSAAPkhKOoIKRaHx1HKkLDiCsMmJfWDsngUyROdyhebReLJaHZW55Um074sgzydskK8nXtlQi1YdjqjtScQGcICYAJxOGz5kyopYDpAAWhRTkNxTd9CRNgw9FYY5swgAYrRlBB1CYAExzus2wjbIA)

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer.  Nice approach!